# Android Room prevent rollback

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

My Transaction rolls back even though `SQLiteConstraintException` is caught. Is there a way to prevent the rollback in case of an exception?

Say I do a deletion that violates a foreign key constraint.

```
@Transaction
fun deleteProduct(p : Product) {
    deleteSomeOtherEntityByProductId(p.id)
    try {
      deleteProductViolatingContstraint(p)
    } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
      // there are SomeOtherEntity's referencing this product
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

In this case, after the transaction is finished, the `SomeOtherEntity` gets restored even though the exception is caught.

Comment: You don't show us the relevant code, schema and SQL. What do you expect the database to do when a constraint is violated by (new?) data? It can't insert the data so it will roll back the transaction.

Comment: @Corion I just updated the question with a code sample. Please, take a look